# Can't access Xserve through Aventail SSL VPN with AD authentication

Tags: osx-server, vpn, ssl

In testing our Aventail SSL VPN with Mac clients we're finding that once connected to the VPN we can't access Xserve shares when authenticating via Active Directory like we normally do on our internal network.  This is in Aventail's browser-based landing page.  A log-in box pops up and we enter the user's ID and password but it won't connect.  We CAN access Xserve shares using an admin account on the Xserve.  Windows shares are accessible with no problems.

Has anyone else seen this problem and found a way to access Xserve with AD authentication?

Comment: As a follow-up does anyone know what authentication method Aventail uses to access xServe?  It's obviously not using Active Directory.